# Try to have a vtkInteractorStyleImage with vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I'm trying to build an application with Qt and VTK. I want to display a 3D image (DICOM) in a widget like `QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget` and be able to change slices using the mouse wheel (and other thigs).

I was inspired by this example: https://examples.vtk.org/site/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOMSeries/ and I'm trying to run it under Qt.

The beginning of interactor is:

```
// Define own interaction style.
class myVtkInteractorStyleImage : public vtkInteractorStyleImage
{
public:
    static myVtkInteractorStyleImage *New();
    vtkTypeMacro(myVtkInteractorStyleImage, vtkInteractorStyleImage);
```

My problem concerns the definition of the interactor. Here is the code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
imageViewer->SetInputConnection(_reader->GetOutputPort());
imageViewer->SetSliceOrientationToYZ();

...

// Create an interactor with our own style (inherit from
// vtkInteractorStyleImage) in order to catch mousewheel and key events.
// vtkNew<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor;

vtkNew<vtkGenericRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor;

vtkNew<myVtkInteractorStyleImage> myInteractorStyle;

vtkNew<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> renderWindowCenter;

// Make imageviewer2 and sliceTextMapper visible to our interactorstyle
// to enable slice status message updates when scrolling through the slices.
myInteractorStyle->SetImageViewer(imageViewer);

myInteractorStyle->SetStatusMapper(sliceTextMapper);

imageViewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);

// Make the interactor use our own interactorstyle
// cause SetupInteractor() is defining it's own default interatorstyle
// this must be called after SetupInteractor().

renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(myInteractorStyle);

this->ui->qvtkWidgetCenter->setRenderWindow(renderWindowCenter);

imageViewer->SetRenderWindow(renderWindowCenter);

// Crash if do that : 
//renderWindowCenter->GetInteractor()->SetInteractorStyle(myInteractorStyle);

imageViewer->Render();
```

I tried to change the interactor classes using: `QVTKInteractor` and `vtkGenericRenderWindowInteractor` in particular, without success..

Thanks for your help !